# IntelliJ debugger Cannot find local variable 'FileNotFoundException762_DebugLabel'. What is going on?

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, intellij-idea, filenotfoundexception

Whenever I debug an unit test in IntelliJ using the build in remote debugger, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find local variable 'FileNotFoundException762_DebugLabel'
url= file:/Users/rutgerterheide/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0/d044c784e41d026778693fb44a8026c1fd9a7506/jaxb-api.jar
```

I don't know what is going on and why IntelliJ keeps giving me this error. Does anyone know what could be causing this and how to fix it?

When I look up the path in Finder I can see indeed that there is no `jaxb-api.jar`.
Now I could add it manually but this is cached data so that doesn't make sense.
I have tried deleting everything in the `/Users/rutgerterheide/.gradle/caches` folder and rebuilding but it didn't work.
I have also tried switching to `JDK 1.8` in the project structure of IntelliJ but that gave me the same result.

I use `Gradle 6.8` and `OpenJDK 11`. The project is in `Spring Boot` and I am running `MacOS 13.3.1 (22E261)`.
My `build.gradle` contains the following code which might be related (they are installed):

```
configurations {
    saxon

    compile.exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    compile.exclude group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', module: 'jaxb-impl'

}


dependencies {

    implementation "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.3"


}
```

This is my IntelliJ version information:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-231.8109.175, built on March 28, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+10-b829.5 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 10
Registry:
debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
ide.experimental.ui=true
editor.minimap.enabled=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.jetbrains.jax.ws (231.8109.90)
com.intellij.bigdatatools (231.8109.175)
aws.toolkit (1.64-231)

Kotlin: 231-1.8.20-IJ8109.175
```

I just don't expect it to fail and debug the test as usual.

Comment: Have you installed the listed dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my project locally and cloned it again from Git.
After loading it IntelliJ the debugger worked again.